# Why is my home-made feta cheese bland?

Tags: cheese, ingredient-selection, cheese-making, feta

I tried making feta cheese yesterday. I used a mesophilic culture from a well-known cheese supply house and it doesn’t have the “bite” I like with feta. The company I ordered my original kit from is no longer in business. What culture is recommended for a feta cheese, or what did I do wrong?

Comment: Can you go into further detail of your process for making the feta cheese? As the question stands, it's hard to tell if you did something wrong without knowing the details behind your process.

Answer (score 6):

Just one day?

Feta is assembled in one day but it is pickled in a brine for at least a week. Recipes I've used call for 10 days.

This time gives bacteria extra time to work and make the product more sour.

I've had good success just using buttermilk as my mesophilic starter. I suspect your starter will be better than mine.

Just give it time.

Comment: +1 I also noticed store-bought feta does become stronger the longer you keep in in the fridge.